# set class path in java from command line .dll file

Tags: java, classpath

I am using netbeans and by setting the VMoptions to:

```
-Djava.library.path=C:\Users\a\Desktop\temp\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\auth\x64
```

my program works perfect. I am trying to run the program from command line. I have tried the following but non seems to be working:

```
- java -Djava.library.path=C:\Users\a\Desktop\temp\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\auth\x64\sqljdbc_auth.dll  
 // shows the java usage

- System.setProperty("java.library.path","C:\\Users\\a\\Desktop\\temp\\sqljdbc_4.0\\enu\\auth\\x64");
 // wrote it in the code but nothing is happening.
```

Please let me know if I am doing something wrong or there is an alternative way to do it.

Comment: The first one is just running `java` and setting a system property; you need to actually *run* something with it, like a class or a jar with appropriate manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:

Place the DLL in your `Windows/<SYSTEM>` folder. Make sure to place the right one (32-bit/64-bit). Then try to run it.

Make sure the DLL you are using is the right one. Your Java JRE and NetBeans JRE may be different, e.g., 32-bit JVM vs 64-bit JVM.